# How to Edit ID Field Values in Visio 2016 Gantt Chart?

Tags: charts, microsoft-visio, gantt

### ISSUE:

I'm a Visio newbie, so be gentle with me.

I created a Gantt chart using the New > Gantt Chart > Blank > US Units. Then I entered my dates and all went well. Now I need to edit the default field text. For instance, the "ID" column has items like "1, 2, 3" -- single digits. But, for my chart, I need it to say "1.0", "2.0", "3.0", etc.

### WHAT I'VE TRIED:

I researched the issue and keep running into something about "editing a master shape copy" -- it's confusing, and looks tedious. I don't understand how I could even do that since I started from a dynamically, automatically generated template.

These two videos were helpful, but didn't cover the issue of editing fields:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3R0o_ReapA
- https://www.lynda.com/Office-tutorials/Creating-Gantt-chart/260/25615-4.html

I even tried just creating my own column, and set the header field type to "user defined decimal", ***but when I enter a decimal number, like "1.0", the zero disappears***!

### MY QUESTIONS

How can I easily edit the text of automatically generated fields in Visio Gantt charts?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please don't include taglines in your questions and answers.

Comment: @DavidPostill What is a tagline?

Comment: Your name, website etc. We can see your name underneath your avatar. Your website (if you have one) belongs in your profile.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks for the clarification. I will leave that out from now on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK with adding another column, pls add one of type "user defined text" and then you can add put values like 1.0, 2.0 in it.

Else if you are aware of how to use the Shape Sheet https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff767544.aspx, you can set the Protection>Lock Text Edit value to 0 in the Shape Sheet, and then you'll be able to right click> Edit Text and change the values in the ID column. You'll need to do this for each row if you've already created your gantt chart though, or you can write a Macro for it. If you are creating it afresh, you can do this for one row, and then copy paste the row, the pasted row will not have text editing locked.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I already tried adding a new column, just the way you described. Although I can can input "2.0", when I save the file it has reverted back to "2". :( That makes me suspect this issue is an autoformatting or autocorrect issue with Visio, but I don't know enough about Visio to know for sure.

Comment: That's odd, I added the new column as "user defined **text**" and it retained the 2.0 as is even after I closed and opened the file.

Comment: I wish I know what settings are different on yours than mine. :( In the end, I had to do a workaround: I painstakingly edited the numbers using Acrobat DC Pro.